# First steps with Selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I am trying to move the first steps in web scraping. I read about selenium and seems to me that it fit for what i am looking for. But i have some problems to start. I am following this tutorial [selenium getting started](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) and i am trying to compile the first example with my linux ubuntu. I have compiled in this way

> javac -classpath selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar Example.java

i have started selenium server with

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar

but i can't run Example. This way doesn't works

> java Example

and this way too

> java -classpath selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar Example

I guess that the grammar is wrong, but where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the current directory in the classpath like so:

```
java -cp .:selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar Example
```

Also since you did not actually put the `Example.java` in `org.openqa.selenium.example`, you probably want to delete the `package org.openqa.selenium.example` in the first line of the source.

Answer (score 0):

While writing code in Java a better approach would be using an IDE like Eclipse. Once you link the JARs and import them in your Java classes you can write your code quickly and efficiently.

On top of that, Eclipse has lot of plugins for testing software like Junit, TestNG's to help you create better test suites.

Not to mention a Java IDE is always helpful in debugging test code. Here is a tutorial on how to setup Eclipse with Selenium: [link](http://selftechy.com/2011/05/31/setting-up-selenium-with-eclipse)

Hope it helps.